# WPF HyperLink opens WebBrowser embedded within program

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have the following HtmlTextBlock for WPF Library included within my program: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/htmltextblock.aspx

Now, I've got the following code that's supposed to implement the HtmlTextBlock:

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.tweeter.Content = twt.User.Username;
    //AddHandler(Hyperlink.ClickEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)Hyperlink_Click);
    ImageSourceConverter conv = new ImageSourceConverter();
    this.tweetImage.Source = (ImageSource)conv.ConvertFromString(twt.User.AvatarURL);
    string txt = twt.Text;
    Regex regx = new Regex("(http|ftp|https)://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(txt);
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        int strt = txt.IndexOf(m.Value);
        int end = strt + m.Value.Length;
        if (strt != -1)
        {
            txt = txt.Insert(end, "[/a]");
            txt = txt.Insert(strt, "[a href=" + m.Value + "]");
        }
    }

    this.tweetText.Html = txt;
    string source = "web";
    if (twt.SourceName != null)
        source = twt.SourceName;
    string dateString = twt.DatePosted;
    const string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy";
    DateTime my_date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
    ts = DateTime.Now - my_date;
    string date = "date";

    // Date Parsing
    if (ts.Days > 0)
    {
        string month = "Mo";
        switch (my_date.Month)
        {
            case 1:
                month = "Jan";
                break;
            case 2:
                month = "Feb";
                break;
            case 3:
                month = "Mar";
                break;
            case 4:
                month = "Apr";
                break;
            case 5:
                month = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                month = "June";
                break;
            case 7:
                month = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                month = "Aug";
                break;
            case 9:
                month = "Sep";
                break;
            case 10:
                month = "Oct";
                break;
            case 11:
                month = "Nov";
                break;
            case 12:
                month = "Dec";
                break;
        }
        date = String.Format("on {0}, {1} {2}, {3}", my_date.DayOfWeek.ToString(), month, my_date.Day, my_date.Year);
    }
    else if (ts.Hours > 0)
        if (ts.Hours == 1)
            date = "1 hour ago";
        else
            date = string.Format("{0} hours ago", ts.Hours);
    else if (ts.Minutes > 0)
        if (ts.Minutes == 1)
            date = "1 minute ago";
        else
            date = string.Format("{0} minutes ago", ts.Minutes);
    else if (ts.Seconds > 30)
        date = string.Format("{0} seconds ago", ts.Seconds);
    else
        date = "just now";

    this.sourceLabel.Content = String.Format("posted {0} from {1}", date, source);

    //tweetText.ContextMenu.StaysOpen = false;
    }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(tweetText.Text);
}

private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Hyperlink)
    {
        Process.Start((e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink).NavigateUri.ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when one of the hyperlinks is clicked, the program opened the link in the default browser, as determined by the EventHandlers shown in the code. However, it also opens a WebBrowser control embedded within the program itself.

I have hunted through the source code, and I found nothing that contained the word 'WebBrowser' or anything similar, so I assume it's not the library.

Could it be a WPF issue? Am I doing something wrong? It's getting quite frustrating.

**Edit:** Just fixed the issue. It was because I was using the ClickEvent instead of the RequestNavigateEvent.

Comment: Are you saying that you want it to open the default browser and that a web browser control is being created and placed somewhere on your WPF window (covering the whole thing?) and navigating to that page?

Comment: Yeah, I want it to open in the default browser, but it does both - opening in the default browser, and creating a web browser control and placing it in the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of will be opening the URL in the default browser

```
Process.Start((e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink).NavigateUri.ToString());
```

Removing that should stop the browser opening. To open the uri in the web browser control you need to set the source property.

```
webBrowser.Source = (e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink).NavigateUri.ToString();
```

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that there is a WebBrowser control being created within the program, and I have no idea why it is being created because I haven't coded anything to create it.